React Native: Calling an export function to change a useState variable in other component
If I want to call an export function (incomingNotification) from A.tsx file to another B.tsx (outside of a component call). In component A, when the user calls the function incomingNotification, a reactive state called newNotification is set by setNewNotification. Keep in mind that (newNotification and setNewNotification) useState is in component B. How can I implement this?
I think useContext could solve this but how?!

You can communicate between components in several ways, you can do it directly using the PropDrilling concept, you can use a Custom Hook or use ContextApi.
Example 1(PropDrilling):
You can pass state and function to update state through component properties. If components A and B are siblings and you have a parent component that wraps them, you can keep state in the parent component and pass it to A and B.
Parent
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import A from './A';
import B from './B';

const ParentComponent: React.FC = () => {
  const [newNotification, setNewNotification] = useState<any>(null);

  return (
    <div>
      <A setNewNotification={setNewNotification} />
      <B newNotification={newNotification} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default ParentComponent;

A.tsx
import React from 'react';

type AProps = {
  setNewNotification: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<any>>;
};

const A: React.FC<AProps> = ({ setNewNotification }) => {
  const handleNotification = () => {
    setNewNotification({ message: 'New notification!' });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleNotification}>Notify</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default A;

B.tsx
import React from 'react';

type BProps = {
  newNotification: any;
};

const B: React.FC<BProps> = ({ newNotification }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {newNotification && <div>{newNotification.message}</div>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default B;

Example 2(Custom Hook):
You can create a custom hook to manage shared state. This works well if you're dealing with simple global state and don't need to pass update functions to lots of different components.
useNotification.ts
import { useState } from 'react';
    export const useNotification = () => {
      const [newNotification, setNewNotification] = useState<any>(null);
    
      return { newNotification, setNewNotification };
    };

A.tsx
import React from 'react';
import { useNotification } from './useNotification';

const A: React.FC = () => {
  const { setNewNotification } = useNotification();

  const handleNotification = () => {
    setNewNotification({ message: 'New notification!' });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleNotification}>Notify</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default A;

B.tsx
import React from 'react';
import { useNotification } from './useNotification';

const B: React.FC = () => {
  const { newNotification } = useNotification();

  return (
    <div>
      {newNotification && <div>{newNotification.message}</div>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default B;
Example 3(ConextApi):
You can use useContext to share state between different components, it is a little more complex, but I will give you an example and you can research a little more:
First, create a NotificationContext.tsx file where you define the context and provider:
import React, { createContext, ReactNode, useState, useEffect } from 'react';

type NotificationContextProps = {
  children: ReactNode;
};

type NotificationContextType = {
  newNotification: any;
  setNewNotification: (newState: any) => void;
};

const initialValue = {
  newNotification: null,
  setNewNotification: () => {},
};

export const NotificationContext = createContext<NotificationContextType>(initialValue);

export const NotificationProvider = ({ children }: NotificationContextProps) => {
  const [newNotification, setNewNotification] = useState(initialValue.newNotification);

  return (
    <NotificationContext.Provider value={{ newNotification, setNewNotification }}>
      {children}
    </NotificationContext.Provider>
  );
};

At your application's entry point, wrap your components with the NotificationProvider:
App.tsx
import React from 'react';
import { NotificationProvider } from './NotificationContext';
import A from './A';
import B from './B';

const App: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <NotificationProvider>
      <A />
      <B />
    </NotificationProvider>
  );
};

export default App;

In component A, you can use useNotification to access and set state:
A.tsx
import React from 'react';
import { useNotification } from './NotificationContext';

const A: React.FC = () => {
  const { setNewNotification } = useNotification();

  const handleNotification = () => {
    setNewNotification({ message: 'New notification!' });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleNotification}>Notify</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default A;

In component B, you can access the updated state:
B.tsx
import React from 'react';
import { useNotification } from './NotificationContext';

const B: React.FC = () => {
  const { newNotification } = useNotification();

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{newNotification.message}</div>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default B;

